# Prove that the number of roots with positive real part is $n-1$ when $n$ is odd, $n$ when $n$ is even

Tags: complex-analysis

So my question is to show that $f(z)$ in  the picture has $n-1$ roots with positive real part if $n$ is odd, and $n$ when $n$ is even. I tried to use argument principle, but i found that in both cases there are n roots with positive real part. I know it's wrong since there are no positive real root and every solution with positive real part has another root which is conjugate of it. But I dont know where i made mistake. Anyone can help me? Thanks!
[image: My solution]